# Shell script to send gps coordinates to emulator?

Tags: android

I woule need a bunch of gps coordinates for test data.  I thought about if it's possible to use adb shell for creating a quick shell script which generates a range of gps coordinates in a for loop. 
But I still don't figured out how to start gps service in shell like gps fix in telnet.

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could do the scripting outside the device. `tellandroid` is [a recently-released Python utility](https://github.com/vbabiy/tellandroid) that exposes Android Debug Console operations to your development computer's command line, so you can run:

```
tellandroid geo set [--host=<host>] [--port=<port>] [--] <lat> <long>
```

and such. Then, your loop would be on your development machine (e.g., as part of a test suite) rather than trying to do it on-device.

Answer (score 0):

You can send gps coordinates directly from the eclipse IDE, change the perspective to DDMS.

Best regards

Comment: but there's no batch option to send coordinates continously